# onDestroy() is calling even though alert box is there in screen

Tags: android

i am displaying alert box in potrait mode..if i change to landscape alert box is not displaying and it is calling onDestroy() when i chnage mode..

can any one help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rotating your phone will cause the Activity to go through [the lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). You can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state) to see how you can save and restore the state of your activity during orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you show dialogs using `Activity.onCreateDialog()` method then activity will manage dialog creation for you. In other case you have to show and dismiss dialogs every time activity is destroyed and recreated.